# How do I add a split vmdk to Glance in OpenStack?

Tags: image, virtualization, openstack

I'm virtualizing a few servers in OpenStack. I already created the virtualmachines into VMDK format (VMWare), but the virtual disks were split into 2GB files. After I copied the files into OpenStack I realized that Glance (OpenStack's image management service) only adds the image of the specific file that I point it torwards.

This brings me to my present issue. Is there a way of adding a split VMDK to Glance?

Do I have to merge it back into one image?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find anyway of adding slit file VMs to OpenStack, but I did find that I could merge the virtual machine files into one. Although it's somewhat inconvenient to manage 200GB files it's still a viable solution.

http://www.mahmoudthoughts.com/2009/07/merge-2gb-vmdk-files-to-one-single-vmdk.html